# GRUB and FreeDOS

Tags: grub, freedos

I have a HD with GNU/Linux and FreeDOS flashdrive.
I want to place those FreeDOS partition (2GB) on my HD.

`fdisk`, `dd`, all things are o'key, but I can't make my GRUB load those OS.
I was try all of the things from the Internet - I have ten FreeDOS strings in GRUB and no one is working.
When I run `update-grub`, os-prober says that FreeDOS found and make this grub.conf thing:

`set root (hdx,x)
chainloader +1`

It doesn't work. `parttool`, `drivemap`, `linux16` and some other things fom Internet also doesn't work.

upd.
This line it shows after boot (if don't go into reboot of course):
`FreeDOS FAT kernel GO!`

Comment: 1. can you boot freedos from the USB flash drive?  2. did you make the HDD partition bootable with `sys` in freedos?  3. if you don't need to save any files to the freedos image while running it, you can use `memdisk` from `syslinux` to boot an ISO image containing freedos (that's what I do to make bootable DOS images, e.g., for flashing BIOS)

Comment: 1. Of course I can boot from USB
2. No, I haven't heard about it. It will write right into bootsector and break my grub, isn't it?
3. No way, I need fully functional OS with rw.